# Is it possible to have commands available in specific directories only?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to have a directory isolated `bin` folder? All packages installed to be available only in that specific directory?

For example I have a directory `~/projects` and I would like to have `git` command available only in that folder.

Comment: No, impossible without gross hacks, I'd say. And why would you want this? Sounds like an XY-problem. What do you *actually* want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @Jens I'm up for gross hacks :)

Comment: Install `git` in a dedicated directory, and shadow `cd` with a function that adds and removes that directory to your `PATH` when you enter/leave a directory under `~/projects`. I don't really see what problem that would solve that would be worth the effort, though.

Comment: I'd approach this by having a `git` shell function that checks whether you're in the right directory, calls through to the *real* git command if you are, and fails otherwise. An external tool that hooks into `cd` is going to have a lot more overhead.

Comment: Git was an example. My goal was to have specific env per directory and `direnv` seems to be the tool that I was looking for. Thanks all for help.

Comment: Putting a relative directory in your `PATH` -- ie. `PATH=$PATH:./bin` would do the trick with much less performance overhead, albeit with significantly more risk security-wise (if someone else creates a `/tmp/bin`, you'd be at risk if you ever `cd`'d into `/tmp`). Of course, if you don't want this to apply to subdirectories, that defeats that too (but, well, question didn't specify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be interested in using one of these two tools:

1. https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv
2. https://github.com/direnv/direnv

The first tool (`autoenv`, mostly written in Bash) is simpler to install and use but is not maintained anymore, and the second tool (`direnv`, mostly written in Go) provides more features, including the ability to unset environment variables.

For more details on their respective features, you can take a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/159).